# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC and Identity in EF Core - resource based authorization

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a project for learning purposes. I want to implement resource-based authorization for the users. I have developed a protected method `UserId()` in the controller, which I call on the get and post methods, Something like the code shown below.

I just wanted to ask, is this solution okay or there is even a better way to do this using the Identity framework, any ideas are very much welcomed :)

```
// protected UserId method
protected string UserId()
{
    return User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
}

// GET view for categories, here I call the UserId method to check if items for that user exist.
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<Category> model = _categoryService.GetCategories().Where(x => UserId().Contains(x.UserId)).ToList();
    return View(model);
}

// POST method for category
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(Category category)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        category.UserId = UserId();
        _categoryService.CreateCategory(category);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    
    return View(category);
}

// my Category model
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this solution is the best one. The FindFirstValue method is directly find the claims according to the claimType.

This will just search the value inside the claims(in the server memory), it will not contact the sql server.